# Stochastic processes and coin flip

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Let $ .., X_{-1}, X_0, X_{1}, ..$ and $.., Y_{-1}, Y_0, Y_{1}, ..$ be two i.i.d processes(individually).

We construct the processes Z, W by fair coin flips where the result is $R \in \{0, 1\}$.

For Z, the coin is flipped once and either X or Y is selected.
So, $Z_n = RX_n + (1-R)Y_n$

For W, the coin is flipped at every time n. 
Hence, $W_n = R_nX_n + (1-R_n)Y_n$, where $R_n$ is the result of the coin flip at time n.

Now I'm being asked if $Z$ and $W$ are i.i.d and stationary processes.

My initial thought was that since Z is determined after the coin flip, it is either $X$ or $Y$ during the process. Thus, i.i.d and stationary.
Also, $W$ alternates between $X$ and $Y$ hence it is nor i.i.d and stationary.

However, the answer says the opposite. What is wrong in my reasoning ?

Comment: I think it matters when the coin is flipped for $Z$.  I notice that $X$ and $Y$ extend infinitely in both directions.  If they are indexed in time, that presents a problem for $Z$ since the coin must be flipped at some time.  $W$ doesn't have such a problem, however, since its coin is flipped at *every* time.  If they aren't indexed in time, then neither are $Z$ and $W$, so it makes no sense to ask whether they are stationary.  The question then becomes, what is $Z_t$ for $t \lt t_0$ where $t_0$ is when the $Z$ coin is flipped?

Comment: They're indexed in time and it extends infinitely in both sides.

Comment: So what is the value of $Z$ before its coin is flipped?

Comment: $Z$ is strictly defined after the flip I guess. I was talking about $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: So if it's undefined before the flip, does it change when it's time-shifted? Seems to me a value is different from no value.

Comment: Also consider the distribution of $Z_{t_0}$ vs that of $Z_{t_0 +1}$ if $t_0$ is when the $Z$ coin is flipped.  Are these independent? Identical? Compare this to $W$.  How does the distribution of $W_n$ compare to that of $W_{n+k}$ for arbitrary $n$ and $k$?  Are they independent? Identical?

Comment: I see. That come to my mind too after learning my answer was wrong. So the key is W has same pmf for all times. Hence i.i.d and stationary.

Comment: Where as Z has different pmf for for t = 0 and t > 0. Right ?

Comment: Correct.  More precisely for stationary what matters is that the *joint* distributions are the same for any two times, separated by the same time interval.  These need not be independent, though, provided they depend on each other in a regular way across all times. For $i.i.d.$, on the other hand, it only matters that the distribution function is the same at all times, and that it doesn't correlate with the values at other times.  It still might be a function of $t$, though. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985269/must-i-i-d-stochastic-process-be-stationary?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, I got that a little bit wrong with respect to i.i.d.  I.i.d Variables can't depend on time, so i.i.d is a stronger condition than stationary.  The question I linked to concerned the law of large numbers, though, and the OP was confused about the requirement of finite means for LLN to hold.  My bad.  For an example of a process that is stationary but not i.i.d, consider $V_n=\frac {R_n +R{n-1}} 2 X_n +\left(1- \frac {R_n +R{n-1}} 2 \right)Y_n$